# Android/Firebase - Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type **my object**

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the values of each node under "templates."

[image]

For example, "eght" (just random test name), contains an ArrayList of ArrayLists. So, ArrayList<.ArrayList>.

I just need to get the values once, so I'm using a single event listener:

```
mTemplateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
     new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          for(DataSnapshot templateSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

               // I've tried a million different things here, but all result in the error
              // This is the error line
              MapFoo mapFoo = templateSnapshot.getValue(MapFoo.class);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    // ...
                }
            });
```

I always end up with this:

```
Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.appname.template_editor.MapFoo
```

The last part being any object I try.

Here's MapFoo:

By the way, I"m using a Map because when I debug, the nodes seem to be in HashMap form. I've also tried a HashMap object with the same error. I've also tried several other objects to try to make it work with no success.

```
public class MapFoo {
public Map<String, ArrayList> mapList;

public MapFoo(){

}

public Map getMapList(){
    return mapList;
}

public MapFoo(Map<String, ArrayList> mapList){
    this.mapList = mapList;
}
```

}

Another variation I tried:

```
public class MasterListTemplateClass {

public String templateName;
public ArrayList<ArrayList> arrayList;

public MasterListTemplateClass() {
}

public MasterListTemplateClass(String templateName, ArrayList<ArrayList> arrayList) {
    this.templateName = templateName;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

public String getName() {
    return templateName;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList> getList() {
    return arrayList;
}
```

}

I just can't get any of this to work. I simply need the values in my database!

Comment: Is the `ArrayList` without type argument your own class or just the raw type?

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation to make your code easier to read.

Comment: 1st comment: Yes, it is just the normal type. 2nd: Edited the line that's causing the error. Also, what's wrong with my indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remembered this post. Have found the answer. When you're working with maps in Firebase, if you have an int as a string (1 vs "1"), Firebase reads that as an int. Whether you inputted it as a string or not. So what I did was add "_key" to the numbers ("1_key") which forced Firebase to read it as a string and not an int. This fixed things right up

Answer (score 2):

instead of number ids like 0,1,2 give them a name to be able to shape ur model
 as i am not sure if it is possible to make a model with number names.

e.g. name 0,1,2 as days, title, dimen respectively and create following model

```
public class MyModel{

    public String days;
    public String title;
    public String dimen;

    public MyModel(){

    }

    public String getDays(){
        return this.days;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getDimen(){
        return this.dimen;
    }
}
```

Then reach this model via 2 loops by calling 2 snapshot.getChildren()

```
 for(DataSnapshot templateSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     for(DataSnapshot snap : templateSnapshot.getChildren()){


              MyModel model = snap.getValue(MyModel.class);
                    }
                }
...
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why they're numbers, that was just how it was set automatically. I'll try to change those though.

Comment: @therealccarter how does your MapFoo class looks like after your change?